# How to capture local storage from browser using Jmeter?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, local-storage, jmeter-plugins

There is a URL. The browser generates a new key and value dynamically every time when I launch the URL. And that is stored in local storage. Also when this url is launched it redirects to an auth page. That time the Key and value are getting disappeared. Actually this key and value are being dislayed for only less than 2 seconds.

I want to capture that Key and Value before it gets disappeared. I am also using jp@gc webdriver. I am launching it in chrome.

**I am unable to retrieve the key and value from local storage.**

Here is my groovy script.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5KtG.png)

Here is my response for it from view results tree.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7COo.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post images of code, just put the code into your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all posting code as an image is a disrespect to the community, [please don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2897748)
2. Here is the code to get first key from the local storage name and value:

   ```
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
   WDS.browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
   def allKeys = WDS.browser.executeScript('return Object.keys(window.localStorage);')
   WDS.vars.put('localStorageKey', allKeys[0])
   WDS.vars.put('localStorageValue', WDS.browser.executeScript('return window.localStorage.getItem(window.localStorage.key(0));'))
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
   ```

   and demo that it works:

   [image]

   If it doesn't work in your specific case you should reach out to your application developers, as per [Local Storage description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

   > The localStorage read-only property of the window interface allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; **the stored data is saved across browser sessions**.

   so the value should be there even if you close your browser and open it again and it shouldn't "being dislayed for only less than 2 seconds".

In case if the value leaves only 2 seconds you can use i.e. [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-waits) to fetch its value from DOM (or the local storage), something like:

```
def wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(5))
def targetKey = wait.until (webdriver -> webdriver.executeScript('return window.localStorage.key(0);'))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)